# How many "hidden righteous people" (צַדִיקִים נִסתָּרים) are there?

Tags: tzaddikim

Everywhere I read about it, it says that God keeps the world going for the sake of 36 righteous people that sustain it with their goodness, and if their number ever dips below 36, the world ends.

But the Talmud only said their number is *at least* 36:

> לא פחות עלמא מתלתין ושיתא צדיקי דמקבלי אפי שכינה בכל דרא
> The world has no fewer than thirty-six righteous people in each generation who greet the Divine Presence every day. [Sukkah 45b, Sanh. 97b]

Do any commentators entertain the notion that there could be millions of them?  Why be so pessimistic as to assume we are always sitting on the ragged edge?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81513/how-many-righteous-men-are-in-each-generation

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64025/could-g-d-change-his-mind-about-the-future-of-humanity#comment187163_66186

Comment: @Fred -- How does this answer the question?  See also: "Thus said Rabbi Shim'on bar Yoḥai: The world possesses not less than thirty men as righteous as Abraham." [Gen. R. 35:2]

Comment: As per the [Reishis Chochmah Sha'ar Hayir'ah perek 6](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14032&st=&pgnum=41&hilite=), sitting on the ragged edge is a pretty solid mindset to have....